# Tag management milk and dairy

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-management

Do we really need a tag for both milk and dairy? I think dairy would suffice since it would encompass milk; otherwise, people may be inclined to create cheese or some other tags that fall into a parent category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that [milk](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milk) alone would be a very narrow tag, and probably all of the questions that could be tagged with it would also be applicable to [dairy](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dairy). I retagged the [one question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/154/are-milk-and-dairy-effective-sources-of-calcium) that that had [milk](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milk), so it should be burninated in a few days.

Comment: I tagged with milk and dairy my question for SEO reasons: it increases the number of keywords that potential users search on the web. I also understand your point, so in the end I don't mind choosing one or the other way.

Comment: @Attilio We are aiming for tags to be useful to us, here. The SEO isn't really needed to be honest - we will get pretty good results no matter what, and google is pretty inteligent.